# Github action to deploy in Azure : Error: Cannot find module '@actions/core'

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-pipelines-yaml

I get the following error message when trying to build and push docker image using this action "azure/docker-login@v1":

```html
Run azure/docker-login@v1
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@actions/core'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/work/_actions/azure/docker-login/v1/lib/login.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/azure/docker-login/v1/lib/login.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) ***
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/runner/work/_actions/azure/docker-login/v1/lib/login.js' ]
***
```

This is the relevant portion of my yaml workflow:

```html
build-and-deploy:
        needs: [deploy_checks]
        environment: ${{ needs.deploy_checks.outputs.env_name }}
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        # checkout the repo
        - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
          uses: actions/checkout@main
          
        - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
          uses: azure/login@v1
          with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        
        - name: 'Build and push image'
          uses: azure/docker-login@v1
          with:
            login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
            password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
        - run: |
            docker build . -t ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/image_name:${{ github.sha }}
            docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/image_name:${{ github.sha }}
```

Notice that the workflow runs well before only today I had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be dependency module or permissions issues; ensure that the GitHub action has sufficient permissions to run the workflow.

Check the service principal's information.

Step1:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac \
  --name <SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME> \
  --role "contributor" \
  --scopes /subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> \
  --sdk-auth
```

The resulting output is as follows:

```
{
    "clientId": "<GUID>",
    "clientSecret": "<GUID>",
    "subscriptionId": "<GUID>",
    "tenantId": "<GUID>",
}
```

Step2:
It is necessary to grant GitHub Actions SP permission to pull and push images to ACR.

```
# Get the id 
registryId=$(az acr show --name <registry-name> --query id --output tsv)

# Grant the 'AcrPush' role to SP
az role assignment create --assignee <ClientId> --scope $registryId --role AcrPush

# Grant the 'AcrPull' role to SP
az role assignment create --assignee <ClientId> --scope $registryId --role AcrPull
```

If the Docker-login action is used, ensure the login-server matches the full path of the image.  If it is using the fully qualified path, specify the entire path of the image example, like
`docker push xxx.docker.io/repo/image`

**NOTE: The action to install the dependencies isn't as fast, granted, but at least you don't need to commit dependencies. Make sure to maintain the correct dependency versions. **